# Maven Yui Compressor plugin not running on process-resources

Tags: maven, yui, yui-compressor

I've explicitly stated process-resoures on this plugin, even though this is not necessary according to the documentation: http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/usage_compress.html

When running:

```
mvn net.alchim31.maven:yuicompressor-maven-plugin:compress
```

It runs fine.

When running:

```
mvn process-resources
```

It doesn't run, even though an exec plugin I have on this phase does work.

Here's the relevant portion of my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>

        <executions>
          <execution>
                <phase>process-resoures</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compress</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a minor mistypo at least in the code that you posted.

Should be `<phase>process-resources</phase>` not `<phase>process-resoures</phase>`